# How do I replace more than one character in a string Python

Tags: python, list, input, split, str-replace

Sorry in advance, I'm barely beginning in programming.

I'm struggling with this program more than I thought I would. **Take a look**:

```
string = str(input("Enter a string: "))

delimiter = input("Enter delimiters: ")


s = list(string)

d = list(delimiter)


def split(string, delimiter):

    for i in s:
        if i in d:
            x = string.replace(i, " ")

    print(x)


split(string, delimiter)
```

And the output I'm supposed to get is:

```
Enter a string: Welcome to Python

Enter delimiters: oe
W lc m t Pyth n
```

Here comes the problem: if I enter more than 1 character, the program will only pass the last character I entered and will ignore the others.

Here is the output I'm getting:

```
 Enter a string: Welcome to Python

 Enter delimiters: oe
 Welc me t  Pyth n
```

I will appreciate any help given! Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

the parameter string is passed as a copy and doesn't change by itself. so, every time you set x = string.replace(i, " "). you are once again getting the original string and replacing only the current character i.

this should do the trick:

```
def split(string, delimiter):
    x = string
    for i in s:
        if i in d:
            x = string.replace(i, " ")

    print(x)
```

Comment: OOOOOO So that's what was going wrong. Now I see how it should really be. Thank you!! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub()` for your question :

```
import re

def split(string, delimiter):
    pattern = "[" + delimiter + "]"
    new_string = re.sub(pattern, " ", string)
    return new_string

string = str(input("Enter a string: "))
delimiter = input("Enter delimiters: ")

split(string, delimiter)
```

Comment: Thanks!! I haven't gone over the "re" module yet, but after seeing this program and understanding how it works, now I can get an idea of how it is!. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Daniel. The answer from DSMSTHN is correct but there is an additional note for you.
str doesn't need to be converted into list because it is already iterable. So, here is my version of code.

```py
string = input("Enter a string: ")
delimiter = input("Enter delimiters: ")


def split(string, delimiter):
    for s in string:
        if s in delimiter:
            string = string.replace(s, " ")
    print(string)


split(string, delimiter)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I was almost sure it wouldn't work without lists. I appreciate it!